# Prevent posts with certain post_meta to be edited

Tags: posts, filters, actions, permissions

So I am looking at adding some custom post_meta to posts and I want those posts to not be editable, which will be some content that I am pulling in.

**Here is what I have**:

I have solved the issues when visiting the `Post` post_type and attempting to edit a post with a specific post_meta using this (**This works great in the UI**):

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', function($actions, $post) {
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'global_post', true)) {
        unset($actions['edit']);
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    }

    return $actions;
}, 10, 2);
```

The above hides the "edit" and "quick edit" buttons for posts with specific post_meta in the UI.

However, when visiting the edit link directly (Example: https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=19771&action=edit - I was still able to edit the post.

Is there a way that I can prevent a post from being edited when visiting a link directly? I was able to successfully hide the buttons in the UI, but this would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think an elegant way to accomplish this would be to hook into [`map_meta_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/map_meta_cap/) and deny users as though they do not have the capability to edit the post. This should also gate any other potential work-arounds, such as modifying the post through the REST API or direct POSTing. As an added benefit, it will also take care of omitting the edit links such that you don't need to include your current solution.

```php
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse405452_restrict_global_post_editing', 10, 4 );

function wpse405452_restrict_global_post_editing( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
  if( $cap !== 'edit_post' )
    return $caps;
  
  $post_id = $args[0];

  if( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'global_post', true ) )
    $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    
  return $caps;
}
```

An introduction to roles & capabilities can be found [in the Plugin Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/)

Comment: Thanks so much @bosco, I will be trying this attempt as soon as I get home and testing it out! First time hearing about this hook.

Comment: So I just attempted this and it works great, but the posts that I am pulling in are set are 'pending' status and with this integration, I'm not able to change the status of the post to published when needed, would there be a workaround or could I just keep quick edit available? Otherwise, this is awesome.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities! The easiest would probably be to hardcode an exemption for your user or the admin role or some such - or add a new role to your user and exempt that. I suppose you could also exempt posts with `pending` status... Or maybe just add a link in `post_row_actions` for certain roles which allows you to toggle the status between `pending` and `publish`?